# Did Assyrians have a wig beard?

Tags: assyrian-empire

I was wondering if Assyrians and relative people on far past had beard wigs, artificial beard? Or did they really use that much time on beauty and hair beauty parlor? Or are sculptures just overly detailed and decorated by hair and beard part?

[image: Assyrian ruler]

Comment: It's likely such art were typically depicting rich people, who would have had the leisure and servants to devote to facial hair-care. However, I haven't looked into it. It would be interesting to discover that ancient peoples used [weaves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_hair_integrations) for their facial hair.

Comment: It's probably easier to sculpt a well groomed beard than an ungroomed one. Same or hair.

Comment: It is visible in many depictions that most of these beards are false (wigs).

Answer (score 2):

Mediterranean Cultures oiled and styled their beards with curling irons to create ridges or ringlets or dangly spirals.

Answer (score 1):

The Assyrians did not shave. They had beards. Ancient Egyptian reliefs, such as those at Abu Simbel, showing captured Assyrians depict them with beards.